# How do I access outputs in Shiny renderUI, and write these to multiple .csv / .zip

Tags: r, csv, shiny, zip

I am new to Shiny, apologies if this is obvious and has been asked numerous times, but I've been stuck on this for days.
I've been modifying a dashboard to process analytical chemistry data i.e. it reads in multiple csv files, processes the data (smooths etc.) with various sliders and functions in Shiny, but does not save/download the processed data/output, which I've been trying to do. I don't seem to be able to access the "output" or processed data e.g. as a list of matrices, which I then write out as new .csv files. (I get "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable")
I am competent in R, and have script which works well,  but making this change to Shiny is proving problematic. How do I access the output data of detectedPeaks or baselineCorrectedSpectra to write to csv (or zip up the mutilple csv files)?
Thank you.

```
#Just part of the relevant code - a long script
#server
 baselineCorrectedSpectra <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$bc)) {
      method <- "SNIP"
      hws <- 100
    } else {
      method <- input$bc
      hws <- input$bcHws
    }

    return(lapply(smoothedSpectra(), function(y) {
      bl <- estimateBaseline(y, method=method, hws)
      intensity(y) <- intensity(y)-bl[, 2]
      return(y)

    }))
  })


  detectedPeaks <- reactive({
    return(detectPeaks(baselineCorrectedSpectra(), method=input$pdNoise,
                       halfWindowSize=input$pdHws, SNR=input$pdSNR))
  })


datasetInput <- reactive({
                switch(input$dtset,
                       "peaks" = detectedPeaks(),
                       "centroided" = baselineCorrectedSpectra())
        })

         output$DownloadZip <- downloadHandler(
   filename = function(){
     paste0("Results",".zip")
   },
   content = function(con){
     files <- c()
       tmpdir <- tempdir()
       setwd(tempdir())
 
     for (i in 1:length(s)){
    x<-as.matrix(datasetInput[[i]]) #This doesn't work,how do I access this data?
    y<-metaData(s[[i]])
    f<-(paste("processed", y, sep="_" )) 
    if(input$downloadType == ".csv")
    write.csv(x,f)
    else write.table(x,f)
    files<-c(x,files)
        }
     zip(zipfile=con, files=files)
  },
   contentType = "application/zip"
 )
```

Comment: Where is `s` defined?  `datasetInput` is a reactive, not a list, so I think just `x <- as.matrix(datasetInput())` will get you the current value of `datasetInput`.  As `datasetInput` isn't a list I don't see how you can loop over `s` to get "all possible values" in your current set up.  But without a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's impossible to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. s is defined earlier on in the script (s is a list of the spectra). I've also tried x<-as.matrix(datasetInput()[[i]]) which seems to work.
I'm now running into other problems with permissions of writing new data to Shiny temporary directory, and renaming the output with the original filenames (without the whole directory path included!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is below:

```
x<-as.matrix(datasetInput()[[i]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `()` to `datasetInput`
Can you give this a try:

```
x<-as.matrix(datasetInput([[i]]))
```